# How to define an interface is reasonable in an api? Throw an exception or return a ErrorCodeBean result？

Tags: java, api, interface

How to define an interface is reasonable  in an api? Throw an exception or return a ErrorCodeBean result？the below is the example:

1.1 Interface

```
Dto checkAndSetInfoForApply(String domain, String orderNo);
```

1.2 Dto

```
public class GroupBuyProductResultDto implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 7942969338660852183L;
      private Integer personNum;// 部分选中时必须人数
      private ResultTypeEnum resultTypeEnum;//接口返回类型
      private String  msg;//接口返回信息
```

}

1.3 ResultTypeEnum

```
public enum ResultTypeEnum {
SUCCESS(1,"成功"),
FAIL(2,"失败"),
EXCEPTION(3,"接口异常"),
EXT(4,"扩展");

private int code;
private String desc;

ResultTypeEnum(int code, String desc){
    this.code = code;
    this.desc = desc;
}
```

}

1.4 transfer

```
Dto groupBuyDto = coreservGrouBuyProductService.checkAndSetInfoForApply(domain, orderNo);
    ResultTypeEnum resultTypeEnum = groupBuyDto.getResultTypeEnum();
    switch (resultTypeEnum) {
        case EXCEPTION:
            throw new GroupBuyException("interface error");
        case FAIL:
            break;
        case SUCCESS:
           do somthing．．．
        default:
            break;
    }
```

2.1 interface

```
Dto checkAndSetInfoForApply(String domain, String orderNo) throws Exception;
```

2.2 Dto

```
public class GroupBuyProductResultDto implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7942969338660852183L;
  private Integer personNum;// 部分选中时必须人数
```

2.3 transfer

```
try{
        Dto groupBuyDto = coreservGrouBuyProductService.checkAndSetInfoForApply(domain, orderNo);
    }catch(Exception e){
        wrong...
    }
```

Which way is more appropriate(1 or 2)？

Answer (score 0):

in you scenario the second implement is better,the recommended way is that return a dto or exception dto from service to controller,you should define unified exception handling controller for all exception,you can reference the code of spring-boot 's exception handler.
The example as shown below,

@ControllerAdvice(annotations = RestController.class)
  public class RestExceptionHandler {

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RestExceptionHandler.class);

@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseBody
//@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
private RestResult runtimeExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
    LOGGER.error("---------> error!", ex);
    return RestResultBuilder.builder().failure().build();
}

@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseBody
//@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
private RestResult     illegalParamsExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    BindingResult bindingResult = ex.getBindingResult();
    Map<String, String> errors = Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(bindingResult
            .getFieldErrorCount());
    for (FieldError fieldError : bindingResult.getFieldErrors()) {
        errors.put(fieldError.getField(), fieldError.getDefaultMessage());
    }
    LOGGER.warn("---------> invalid request! fields ex:{}", JSON.toJSONString(errors));
    return RestResultBuilder.builder().errorCode(GlobalErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST).data
            (errors).build();
}

@ExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException.class)
@ResponseBody
//@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public RestResult messageNotReadableExceptionHandler(HttpMessageNotReadableException ex) {
    LOGGER.warn("---------> json convert failure, exception:{}", ex.getMessage());
    return RestResultBuilder.builder().errorCode(GlobalErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST).build();
}

@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException.class)
//@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
@ResponseBody
public RestResult methodArgumentTypeMismatchExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException ex) {
    LOGGER.error("---------> path variable, exception:{}", ex.getMessage());
    return RestResultBuilder.builder().errorCode(GlobalErrorCode.BAD_REQUEST).message(ex.getMessage()).build();
}
```

}

Comment: So in the api in the second way better? Only the service returns to the controller to define the error returned dto? Is that mean?thanks.